# Que significa los parametros de reduce

Tags: javascript

Quiero encontrar la minima suma de un arreglo

es decir de este arreglo [5,4,2,3] la minima suma es 22.

mi solucion es:

```js
function minSum(arr) {
  arr = Object.values(arr).sort((a, b) => a - b);

  var j = arr.length - 1;
  var suma = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 / 2; i++) {
    suma = suma + arr[i] * arr[j];
    j--;
  }
  return suma / 2;
}

console.log(minSum([5, 4, 2, 3]));
```

pero tambien el siguiente codigo seria otra solucion

```js
minSum = a => (a = a.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)).reduce((x, y, i) => x + (y * a[a.length - 1 - i]), 0) / 2

console.log(minSum([5, 4, 2, 3]));
```

No entiendo esta parte: `reduce((x, y, i)`  que son estos parametros y de donde vienen?

Comment: Mira la documentación de [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El parametro `x` se llama acumulador o accumulator. Esta contiene el valor de la operacion anterior retornada. Por ejemplo:

```js
var resultado = [1,1,1,1].reduce(function(acumulador ){ 
  console.log("El valor del acumulador es " + acumulador);
  
  return acumulador+1;
})

console.log("La suma total es " + resultado);
```

Fijate como el valor del parametro acomulator va incrementando de 1 en 1. Esto pasa por la expresion return `acumulador + 1`. Solo para mostrar un ejemplo mas claro, el acumulador seria asi:

```js
var array = [1,1,1,1];
var acumulador = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
{
  acumulador = acumulador + array[i];
}

console.log(acumulador);
```

Nota como se suma el valor del mismo con el valor actual del array. `acumulador = acumulador + array[i];` es lo mismo que `return acumulador + 1;`.

`y` representa el valor actual del array siendo procesado. En el ejemplo arriba, representaria `array[i]`.

Y por ultimo `i`, representa el indice de elemento siendo procesado. En ejemplo este representaria la variable i definida en el for.

Comment: acumulador, no acomulador ;)

Comment: Me hiciste editar toda la pregunta haha. Gracias por la observacion. Editado.

Answer (score 3):

**Sintaxis:**

```
var resultado = arr.reduce(funcion[, valorInicial]);
```

El método `reduce()` aplica una función a un acumulador y a cada valor de un array (de izquierda a derecha) para reducirlo a un único valor.

### Parametros de .reduce:

- `funcion`

Función a ejecutar para cada valor del array, que recibe cuatro parámetros:

**Parámetros de la función:**

> - `valorAnterior`
>
> El valor devuelto (retornado) en la llamada anterior de la función, o
>   el `valorInicial`, si se proveyó. (Ver a continuación.)
>
> - `valorActual`
>
> Elemento actual que está siendo procesado en el array.
>
> - `indiceActual`
>
> Índice del elemento actual que está siendo procesado en el array.
>
> - `array`
>
> El array sobre el cual se llamó el método reduce.

- `valorInicial`

Objeto a usar como primer argumento en la primera llamada de la función.

### Ejemplo Practico:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].reduce(function(valorAnterior, valorActual, indice, vector){
  return valorAnterior + valorActual;
});

// Primera llamada
valorAnterior = 0, valorActual = 1, indice = 1

// Segunda llamada
valorAnterior = 1, valorActual = 2, indice = 2

// Tercera llamada
valorAnterior = 3, valorActual = 3, indice = 3

// Cuarta llamada
valorAnterior = 6, valorActual = 4, indice = 4

// el array sobre el que se llama a reduce siempre es el objeto [0,1,2,3,4] 

// Valor Devuelto: 10
```

Con valor inicial:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].reduce(function(valorAnterior, valorActual, indice, vector){
  return valorAnterior + valorActual;
}, 10);

// Primera llamada
valorAnterior = 10, valorActual = 0, indice = 0

// Segunda llamada
valorAnterior = 10, valorActual = 1, indice = 1

// Tercera llamada
valorAnterior = 11, valorActual = 2, indice = 2

// Cuarta llamada
valorAnterior = 13, valorActual = 3, indice = 3

// Quinta llamada
valorAnterior = 16, valorActual = 4, indice = 4

// el array sobre el que se llama a reduce siempre es el objeto [0,1,2,3,4] 

// Valor Devuelto: 20
```

F**uente y más ejemplos** [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)